# php preg_split explode line by multiple spaces and tabs in fields that may contain spaces too

Tags: php

I need to parse some strings in the following format

```
A 4 "AB5672HMKL" B 9500 8150 39  0000 L XFN "ProductPN"
```

- space, tab or multiple combinations of those delimited
- what is in double quotes are strings

I came up with simplest that worked until today :)

```
$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
```

I discovered that strings can contains spaces too!

```
A 4 "AB5672HMKL OLD" B 9500 8150 39  0000 L XFN "ProductPN"
```

Now obvious my old code isn't working.
Any brilliant idea? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

```
<?php
$line = 'A 4 "AB5672HMKL OLD" B 9500 8150 39  0000 L XFN "ProductPN"';

print_r(str_getcsv($line, ' '));
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/6Qs5e

Comment: excellent, +1 for str_getcsv() but array_filter() just removed 0 character instead of just white spaces

Comment: you need to use it in last. And i didn't see that in my answer links

Comment: @orfruit  don't use `array_filter()` and `array_values()`

Comment: @splash58  i get your point. OP need to leave `array_filter()`  as well as `array_values()` point

Comment: @AlivetoDie just replace `/h+/` to one space before